# Can an image be rolled back?

Tags: container, podman

If I'm working on an image with multiple layers, is it possible to rollback to a previous layer or reset to another layer in the image's stack?

What is the podman equivalent of `git reset --hard HEAD^` on an image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking... you are using podman and you have an image with multiple layers...  You'd like to effectively rollback to an earlier layer.

Rather a lot like git, podman image names are just references to an image id and each image layer should have its own id.

You can view the image layers with the command `podman history` and then add a tag to the layer of your choice using `podman tag`.

---

Eg if you start with a Containerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN echo hello
RUN echo goodbye
RUN echo something else
```

Then build it with:

```
podman build . -t foo
```

You can then view the history:

```
podman history foo
ID            CREATED             CREATED BY                                     SIZE     COMMENT
4eb0380df1fc  6 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c echo something else                 1.02 kB  FROM localhost/foo:latest
aedc2b11640a  About a minute ago  /bin/sh -c echo goodbye                        1.02 kB  FROM localhost/foo:latest
6782b9a36ab3  4 minutes ago       /bin/sh -c echo hello                          2.05 kB  FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest
825d55fb6340  2 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                0 B      
<missing>     2 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:b83df51ab7caf8a...  75.1 MB
```

You can then tag a lower layer

```
podman tag 6782b9a36ab3 bar
```

This is lets you use the image `bar` which is actually a lower (earlier) layer of the image `foo`:

```
podman run -it --rm bar
```

Obviously you don't need to give the image a new name, you could use the same name.  But be careful, when you do this you might lose access to the upper layers that you have removed.